# "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." related

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, profile, provisioning

I use Xcode 4.2 Achive my new version and everthing going well.And I get the .ipa file and I it can be installed on the device before ios 5.0,but when I try to install on ios 5.0 I got "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.",I checked my Developer and Distribution Provisioning Profiles and there is no problems with it.What's that problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you added device UDID to the distribution provision that means you use incorrect sign. Check you Build settings of target and app and check "Code signing" section.

Comment: that was my solution. recently added device udid is the key point